# Does Progressive Web-Apps really works on iOS?

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, progressive-web-apps

I am really confused by `PWA` on my iPhone.

First, before showing my code, I was trying to check how a good web-app look.
Searching in Google for best progressive web-apps i open all of them on my iPhone in `Safari`, and clicked the `Share button` and then `Add To Home Screen`. (Uber, Flipboard, Twitter, Google Maps, Ali-express, etc)

When opening the icons **from home-screen**, it will open `Safari` again with that same page i was at, just like any website.

1. No full screen
2. No separate window (just opens in Safari like a website)
3. No splash screen
4. On Chrome- no "Add to home-screen" button

Basically just a website with an icon.

Then i was trying to do so on my website using Google's `pwacompat` library on my page.

I have added those into the page `head` :

```
<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.webmanifest" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="../images/logo.png">
```

then the JS library at the bottom of my html :

```
<!-- webapp manifast library -->
<script async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pwacompat@2.0.6/pwacompat.min.js" integrity="sha384-GOaSLecPIMCJksN83HLuYf9FToOiQ2Df0+0ntv7ey8zjUHESXhthwvq9hXAZTifA" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

Same again, i am adding this page to home screen, and nothing.
No full screen, no different window, just `Safari`.

**Do i misunderstand a fundamental thing about PWA  ?**

Comment: Have you tested your HTTPS site with the Chrome Lighthouse tool and it gives you no errors? (it is a valid PWA)

Comment: my site is https, as well as all the other sites i mentioned in the question that supposed to be PWA. (Uber,Twitter, etc). It almost seems as if my iPhone just don't want to support it. ( iPhone 8+ with iOS 12+ )

Comment: You can find some info on Safari support for PWAs here: https://medium.com/@firt/whats-new-on-ios-12-2-for-progressive-web-apps-75c348f8e945

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS started very late to open to PWAs and it still needs extra attributes (as you used) to provide the full set of PWA features.

In Chrome DevTools if you go to Application tab (for your application), can you see that the web manifest with its properties is correctly displayed and the service worker as well?

As Mathias said, you need an HTTPS connection to be able to register correctly a service worker. Localhost however is considered "safe" for developing purposes.

I wrote a [series of articles](https://dev.to/paco_ita/a-gentle-introduction-to-progressive-web-apps-step-1-24da) about PWA, you can have a look and follow along to see if you missed anything.

[Here](https://caniuse.com/#search=service%20worker) a list of browsers supporting service workers (to compare with the safari version you are using).

---

**UPDATE**

I answer here to your comments:

1. If some web sites that offers PWAs (eg. Uber, FB) work as PWA on other devices, but not on your phone, then I would try to investigate whether there is a setting missing on your side. I made a quick research and it seems that for iOS users some extra steps are needed to use/enable PWAs:

> The user has to access the PWA URL with Safari and then manually press the Share icon and then “Add to Home Screen.” There is no indication that the visited website is a PWA.

About the "Add to home screen" in Chrome, I could not indeed find any official information when it has been removed. I can only say that I never seen it again since one of the latest versions (v74+).

2. Every pages of a PWAs should be linkable in order to benefit from sharing it via social media apps. Therefore if you have a working PWA and you send links to others, these should work as well. There are no special browser restrictions, given that the app is correctly implemented.

I leave you below some links where other people have similar issues with PWAs and iOS 12.2:

- [Link with discussion](https://discuss.appstudio.dev/t/web-app-not-update-ios-12-2/1550/18)
- [Test PWA](https://superpwa.com/doc/test-pwa-ios-devices/)
- [Article with some tips](https://www.netguru.com/codestories/few-tips-that-will-make-your-pwa-on-ios-feel-like-native) (here there are some suggestions on how to make the PWA work on iOS)

Comment: thanks a lot ! few questions , First it is https (hosted in Firebase), second, there are many different opinions weather Chrome in iOS 12+ has the "add to homescreen" button or not now. I did not see it. Third - all the websites that known to be PWA , did not worked as PWA on my iPhone.

Comment: Something else, if PWA on iOS works only on Safari ( not on Facebook browser or Chrome), so only if i share a link that will be opened IN Safari, can be a PWA. Now given the fact that most people share links on FB/TW/etc, or use Chrome on iPhone, there is no chance almost that my link will find its way to their Safari, and i can not force it, so who can use my PWA anyway ?

Comment: thanks but there are contradictions in your text in number 2) . If Chrome/FB/IG are all based on Apple's webKit, we already know that there is no webapp capabilities in them ( how could there be ? if you browse inside FB app, you obviously can't add the website into your homepage in order to get it as a webapp). Bottom line it seems, that the whole subject is such  overrated and there is nothing new under the sun. (of Apple at least)

Comment: I meant, if we send the link to browsers supporting PWAs without issues. For example by opening the link on an Android Chrome. Indeed if we send the link to another recipient having difficulties with PWA, this won't work. I hope you will be able to fix the issues with your app, hopefully Apple will accept more and more PWAs features.